Wireless disabled
I suddenly cannot enable wifi whether booting from a USB installation stick or booting the system from the hard drive. Kubuntu 24.04
Network manager just says "Wireless is disabled". nmcli shows the 2 wireless adapters and their mac addresses but each one says "sw disabled". Followed several suggestions to no avail.

See https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/300665 and edit the question to include results from the wireless script

What are the exact steps you have tried and any messages or errors you get. Please use edit and add this vital info to the question.

sudo nmcli radio wifi on

I have followed every suggestion I could find. Odd thing is when I run windows 10 in a virtualbox machine and let it use one of the wireless adapters, wireless works fine in the virtualbox machine. It's as if kubuntu suddenly lost the driver's for the wireless adapters completely. Even booting from installation media does the same thing - no wireless. When I first installed 24.04 it asked me for my wireless security key during installation and it connected immediately.
